# How to change a layout for Survey Form Sharepoint?

Tags: form, survey

I want to make a new layout for Form Survey in sharepoint. How to change it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create new Form in SharePoint Designer for your Survey list and customize it.

Comment: No, I want to do it for every Survey list, not for only 1. I want to change a custom template for every Survey list.